# Smarter Editor Tab Labels in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Has anyone found an option/plugin that allows customisation of Editor tabs in Eclipse?

I have started using Eclipse for Pylons development and found that it is easy to do lots of tab hunting when my model and controller files have the same name. I was thinking of just prepending the package name to the file i.e

models/page.py | controllers/page.py |

*(instead of page.py | page.py at the moment)*

Or is this something that I should look at perhaps tring to do a plugin for?

Comment: Google, index me: Vim guitablabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot do that in the standard Eclipse.

If you think this is of general interest to all Pydev users, you should open an issue (with feature request) about it.

If you want to write such a plugin yourself, it shouldn't be too hard. Something like listening to the event of Open Editor and setting the editor part name to something different.

BTW, the editor title has a tooltip which shows the full path.

Comment: Cheers, I will look into raising a feature request.