# Latest eclipse/pydev shows python package names instead of module names in editor window tabs

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just updated to the latest Eclipse classic plus PyDev, and instead of showing the module name (without the .py extension) in the editor window tabs, it shows the python package name (equivalent to the parent folder name).

Does anyone know if this is as per design, and if there's any workaround?  It appears there's no way to customize the tab titles entirely: [3450648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450648/smarter-editor-tab-labels-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go to Eclipse Preferences -> Pydev -> Editor -> Editor caption/icons -> Django modules handling -> Show as regular module

Comment: If you have more than one Views open, this now says "Views (AppName)" instead of just the old "AppName".  I don't need it to say "Views" when it has a Views icon.

Answer (score 1):

The little icon in the window tab, which precedes the tab name, shows whether the file is a model (M), view (V), etc.  This is actually a PyDev django feature; they show "icon + appname" instead of filename, for modules that fit the typical django naming convention.  Takes a bit of getting used to, but it's functional.

I have not found any way of changing the tab names back to the old convention, short of hacking PyDev itself.